# close 2nd new window in javascript

Tags: javascript, window

i am having a problem with my script i am using this.target to open a jquery window at the moment when a user clicks submit. however this is bringing up a 2nd new window.

is there a way i can give the new window thats opening and if that window is open to close it straight away because i don't want this window to open at all.

here's what i have tried:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myform').submit(function() {
        Shadowbox.open({
        content:    '<iframe src="loginin.php" width="500" height="300" scrolling="no" style="overflow:hidden; border:none;"></iframe>',
        player:     "html",
        height:     300,
        width:      500
    });

        this.target = 'shadowbox' 

        if(window.target){
  self.opener = self;
  window.close();
 }


    });
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't whant to open second window, why you open it in your function? Just remove it from sumbit function:

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {/*here code*/});
```

if you want to hide second window Shadowbox has method close() to close current view in popup, just use it `Shadowbox.close()`.